# Does hyperledger fabric smartcontract support more than one go file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Does hyperledger fabric smartcontract support more than one go file?
for example, the go file is too large, so splited into several files.
If support ,how to submit the smartcontract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Chaincode is just like a normal go project. You just need to pass the chaincode path to the folder where you locate the main package files

Example:

```
mycc_folder
____ go.mod
____ main_package_folder
____ ____ main.go
____ ____ something_else.go
____ support_package_folder
____ ____ common.go
____ ____ utils.go


./bin/peer lifecycle chaincode package mycc.tar.gz --path $path_to_mycc_folder/main_package_folder --lang golang --label mycc
```

Comment: If support_package_folder  need to be included in the package, how to  pack it?@Hoai Nam

Comment: The command line above will pack the needed package into a single tar.gz file

Comment: Did you get any problem while installing the packed chaincode?